# Ubuntu running on command line due to insufficient graphics

Tags: nvidia, data-recovery

My problem is that when I was trying to install Nvidia drivers (some 301 version) on Ubuntu 13.04, it evoked a message

> Ubuntu is running on low graphics

After the installation (I am repenting of that installation a lot :(), whenever I reboot my laptop it shows only command line version of Ubuntu 13.04. I could reinstall Ubuntu using usb-stick, but it could cost me loss of important data. I tried to copy my home directory using live Ubuntu through usb-stick, but I get a permissions error.

My problem could have multiple solutions such as

1. I can reinstall Nvidia or integrated Intel graphics driver so that I can continue with my previous installation and data.
2. I can copy the data to an external harddisk through commands (which I don't know how to do) and reinstall Ubuntu (which I know how to do :))
3. I can copy the data though live Ubuntu run through usb-stick to an external hard disk.

Comment: do you remember the commands you ran to install the new driver?

Comment: i install them from ubuntu application center

Answer (score 1):

First, uninstall the current nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

If successful, restart the computer:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: COLYN1337 please tell me about how i can copy files using live usb.
i mean potential solutions 2 and 3 in my questions.